# Prove that the square sum of eigenvalues is no more than the Frobenius norm for a square complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

> Let  $ \boldsymbol{A}=(a_{ij})_{n\times n} $ be a complex square matrix with eigenvalues: $\lambda_1 ,\lambda_2, \dots , \lambda_n $.  Prove that
> $$ \sum_{r=1}^{n} |\lambda_r|^2 \le \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|^2\,.$$
> Furthermore, show that the equality holds if and only if $$\boldsymbol{A^H A=AA^H}\,.$$
> Here, $\boldsymbol{A^H}$ is the conjugate transpose of $\boldsymbol{A}$.

We can write $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n\,|a_{ij}|^2=\operatorname{Tr}(\boldsymbol{AA^H})=\|\boldsymbol{A}\|_F^2,$$
where $\|\_\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.  So this inequality gives a lower bound on $\|\boldsymbol{A}\|_F$, namely
$$\|\boldsymbol{A}\|_F\geq \sqrt{\sum_{r=1}^n\,|\lambda_r|^2}\,.$$

**Edit.**  Another proof of the inequality is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747359/frobenius-norm-and-relation-to-eigenvalues).  However, there is no discussion about the equality case.

Comment: Does $\mathbf{A}^{H}$ represent the complex conjugate of $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: No, it is the conjugate transpose of $\boldsymbol{A}$. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: and your attempt?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the prove. I need help.

Comment: I am afraid that's not good enough, sorry.

Comment: Sorry I donnot understand what "not good enough" means?

Comment: Here's a way to start:  first assume that A is diagonal.  The result follows trivially.  Next assume that A is diagonalizable. If $A^HA = AA^H$ can you show your result for this case?  "Not good enough" means that we are not supposed to do all your work for you --  you should show some attempt at the problem.

Comment: @BettyMock thanks, it is hard to not lose one's patience with some people...

Comment: @IgorRivin the OP is fairly new to this site and perhaps does not fully understand the rules.  I am always patient through the first several iterations.  One can always be impatient later.

Comment: @BettyMock you are a more patient person than I am. I usually can't wait to become impatient :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\mathbf{A}$ is a general square complex matrix (i.e. $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$), we have by Schur decomposition:

$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}$$

Where $\mathbf{Q}$ is a unitary matrix (i.e. $\mathbf{Q}^{-1}=\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}$, where $\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}$ represents the conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{Q}$) and $\mathbf{U}$ is an upper triangular matrix. Multiplying each side by its Hermitian transpose, we get:

$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}=(\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger})(\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger})^{\dagger}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{U}^{\dagger}\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^{\dagger}\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}$$

Taking the trace of both sides and using the property that the Frobenius norm of $\mathbf{A}$ is $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger})$, we have:

$$\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n}|A_{ij}|^{2}=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger})=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^{\dagger}\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger})=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^{\dagger})=\operatorname{Tr}((\mathbf{\Lambda}+\mathbf{N})(\mathbf{\Lambda}+\mathbf{N})^{\dagger})$$

We get the final equality from the property of an upper triangular matrix that it can be written as the sum of a strictly upper triangular matrix $\mathbf{N}$ and a diagonal matrix, which in this case is the matrix with eigenvalues along its diagonal $\mathbf{\Lambda}=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n})$. We also use the property that the conjugate transpose is distributive over matrix addition, i.e. $(\mathbf{\Lambda}+\mathbf{N})^{\dagger}=\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}+\mathbf{N}^{\dagger}$. Therefore we have:

$$\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n}|A_{ij}|^{2}=\operatorname{Tr}((\mathbf{\Lambda}+\mathbf{N})(\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}+\mathbf{N}^{\dagger}))=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}+\mathcal{O}(\mathbf{\Lambda}))$$

And therefore because $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}) \leq \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger} + \mathcal{O}(\mathbf{\Lambda}))$, we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\lambda_{i}|^{2}\leq \sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n}|A_{ij}|^{2}$$

As required.

Note that if a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is normal, i.e. it satisfies $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}$  then $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonalizable, i.e. $\exists \mathbf{P}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger}$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n})$ and $\mathbf{P}$ is unitary.

Multiplying by the complex conjugate of both sides:

$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}=(\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger})(\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger})^{\dagger}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger}$$

Again using the property that the Frobenius norm is $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger})$, we take the trace of both sides:

$$\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}|A_{ij}|^{2}=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger})=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{P}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}\mathbf{P}^{\dagger})=\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\lambda_{i}^{*}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\lambda_{i}|^{2}$$

So we have equality iff $\mathbf{A}$ is normal.

Comment: You did not say what $\mathcal O(\mathbf \Lambda)$ is.  I think it should be $\text{Tr}(\mathbf N \mathbf N^\dagger)$.  Then you can show equality holds in the case when $\mathbf A$ is normal without the second part of the proof.  Also, you did not show the only if.  Otherwise I would upvote your answer.

Comment: Also, you did not show why $\text{Tr}(\mathcal O(\mathbf \Lambda) \ge 0$.