# Doubts about textbook problem about Frobenius norm and sum of squared moduli of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question 4.9 in [*Applied Numerical Linear Algebra*](https://my.siam.org/Store/Product/viewproduct/?ProductId=956) by James W. Demmel (1997) is as follows.

> Let $A$ be $n$-by-$n$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Show that
> \begin{equation}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|\lambda_i\right|^2 = \min_{\det(S)\neq 0}\left\Arrowvert S^{-1}AS\right\Arrowvert_F^2.\end{equation}

The $F$ indicates Frobenius norm. Note that $A$ is not assumed to be diagonalizable.

I found an example that seems to suggest that $\min$ is not correct, while $\inf$ is, at least for my example.

Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ Jordan block, and let $S$ be a $2\times 2$ invertible matrix.
\begin{eqnarray}
S^{-1}AS &=& \frac{1}{s_{11}s_{22} - s_{12}s_{21}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}s_{22} & -s_{12}\\-s_{21} & s_{11}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & 1\\0 & \lambda\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}s_{11} & s_{12}\\s_{21} & s_{22}\end{array}\right)\\
&=& \frac{1}{s_{11}s_{22} - s_{12}s_{21}}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda(s_{11}s_{22}-s_{12}s_{21}) + s_{21}s_{22} & s_{22}^2\\
-s_{21}^2 & \lambda(s_{11}s_{22}-s_{12}s_{21}) - s_{21}s_{22}
)
\end{array}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Let $\delta$ be the (nonzero) determinant of $S$. Then
\begin{equation}
S^{-1}AS = 
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda + s_{21}s_{22}/\delta & s_{22}^2/\delta\\
-s_{21}^2/\delta & \lambda - s_{21}s_{22}/\delta
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{eqnarray}
\left\Arrowvert S^{-1}AS\right\Arrowvert_F^2 &=& \left|\lambda + s_{21}s_{22}/\delta\right|^2
+ \left|s_{22}^2/\delta\right|^2\\
&+& \left|-s_{21}^2/\delta\right|^2 + \left|\lambda - s_{21}s_{22}/\delta\right|^2\\
&=& \left|\lambda\right|^2 + 2\textrm{Re}\left(\lambda\frac{\overline{s_{21}}\overline{s_{22}}}{\overline{\delta}}\right) + \left|\frac{s_{21}s_{22}}{\delta}\right|^2 + \left|\frac{s_{22}^2}{\delta}\right|^2\\
&+& \left|\frac{s_{21}^2}{\delta}\right|^2 + \left|\lambda\right|^2 - 2\textrm{Re}\left(\lambda\frac{\overline{s_{21}}\overline{s_{22}}}{\overline{\delta}}\right) + \left|\frac{s_{21}s_{22}}{\delta}\right|^2\\
&=& 2\left|\lambda\right|^2 + \frac{\left(\left|s_{21}\right|^2 + \left|s_{22}\right|^2\right)^2}{\left|\delta\right|^2}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{Punchline:}~~~~~\left\Arrowvert S^{-1}AS\right\Arrowvert_F^2 ~=~ 2\left|\lambda\right|^2 + \frac{\left(\left|s_{21}\right|^2 + \left|s_{22}\right|^2\right)^2}{\left|\delta\right|^2}
\end{equation}

The term added to $\left|\lambda_1\right|^2 + \left|\lambda_2\right|^2 = 2\left|\lambda\right|^2$ is positive for every invertible matrix $S$, as $\left|s_{21}\right|^2 + \left|s_{22}\right|^2 = 0$ would imply that the bottom row of $S$ is all zeros.

Within the set of invertible matrices one can choose a matrix for which this quantity is as small as desired, so $2\left|\lambda\right|^2$ would be the infimum of the squared Frobenius norm, but not the minimum.

Have I missed something?

Comment: I think you are right. Just take a Jordan block $J$ to the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$. If the equation with min would be correct, then there would be an invertible $S$ such that $S^{-1}JS=0$, which means $J$ is $1\times 1$.

Comment: One can modify the Jordan decomposition to get  $\epsilon$'s on the off-diagonal entries  instead of ones. So the inf is correct.

Comment: The inequality of Schur is $\big \Vert  B \big \Vert_F^{2} \geq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \big \vert \lambda_i\big \vert ^2$ with equality *iff* $B$ is normal. So as printed your text implies every $n\times n$ matrix is similar to a normal matrix, which of course is false.  Inf works though.

Comment: @user8675309: Thank you. I didn't find much on this issue when searching for _inequality of Schur_, but some tweaking of the search led to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747359/frobenius-norm-and-relation-to-eigenvalues).